# Где найти подобный слайдер на wp?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, слайдер

Нужно сделать слайдер как на [этой странице](http://bobs39.ru/biologicheskie-ochistnye-sooruzheni)
Смысл в том, что он показывает на компе по 3 картинки с кнопкой, а на мобиле уже по 1 картинке на всю ширину. Слайдер товаров не подойдет, тк на некоторых страницах будут просто картинки в таком же варианте.
Пробовал smart slider и slider revolution, там функционала отображения количества картинок в ряд в зависимости от ширины экрана не нашел

Answer (score 1):

на данном сайте используется Slick - [ссылка](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

По ссылке есть документация, в том числе как настроить адаптив (настройки вывода слайдов для разных экранов)